# Drupal's SimpleTest not creating copies of custom tables

Tags: drupal, simpletest

I am using the SimpleTest module version 6.x-2.8 with Drupal 6.13. I wrote a custom module, for which I wrote some tests. However, SimpleTest doesn't seem to be creating a copy of the table associated with my custom module, because I get an exception message for every time I try to insert something into the table or query it in the SimpleTest.

All insert queries result into something like this in the SimpleTest results page:
Table 'db_name.simpletest692319new_table' doesn't exist query: INSERT INTO simpletest692319new_table(...)

There is a hook_schema() defined in my .install file for the module. Does anyone know if there's anything else that SimpleTest needs in order to recognize my table and create the copy of it?

Thanks.

Comment: are you enabling the custom module using the setUP function? Something like:

function setUp() {
  parent::setUp('my_module_name');
}

Comment: Also, I am not sure about this but should the hook schema be in .module file rather than the .install file

Comment: jhedstrom: Thanks for your response. I had function setUp() { parent::setUp(); } (no parameter) so I tried passing in my module name in as a parameter, and am still getting the same rsults.


Jeremy: hook schema should be in the .install file.

Comment: Does your hook_install run the drupal_install_schema function? I have seen simpletests work with custom tables so I know it works. could you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have to extend DrupalWebTestCase and add your module to setUp

```
class MyTest extends DrupalWebTestCase {
    function setUp() {
        parent::setUp('mymodule');
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is strange. Your solution works, but what makes it hard to believe, is that despite the module schema not being installed, module specific functions are found and can be executed. So normally you would assume that the module is fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at CCK's implementation of SimpleTest it looks like you need to:

```
  function setUp() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $modules = array_merge(array('my', 'list', 'of', 'modules'), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array('parent','setUp'), $modules);
  }
```